# Ruby on Rails - Rake task not working through Cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake

When I execute a rake task manually, it works fine but when I put the same command in Cron nothing happens:

```
cd /path/to/my/rails/app && rake daily_import
```

The Cron log indicates that the command was issues:

```
CMD (cd /path/to/my/rails/app && rake daily_import)
```

The rake task logs error and success messages, but nothing is recorded to the log, nothing is done at all.  However if I copy and paste the text of the CMD with the same user Cron is running the command in everything works fine.

I'm assuming that running a task in Cron should be the same as typing it in myself, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for mail that the cron daemon might have sent to the user under which the cron job is running.  If a cron job produces output on stderr or stdout, the cron daemon will email that to the owner of the cron job.  If something is going wrong (possibly because of a PATH issue, like Rob suggests above), you might see a helpful error message in an email from the cron daemon.

Answer (score 8):

This thing worked for me

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/my/rails/app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake daily_import'
```

You need to specify /bin/bash -l -c before your task.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking at this with Rails 3.2<>4.0, I had to use this in my crontab:

```
0 * * * * BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/path/to/rails/Gemfile /path/to/bin/bundle exec rake -f /path/to/rails/Rakefile db:hive_enrich RAILS_ENV=production > /var/log/rake_tasks.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me for Rails 3 and rvm integration. I simply execute a bash script:

```
0 * * * * rvmuser /bin/bash -l -c '/path/to/my/bashscript > /tmp/script.log'
```

This doesn't seem to work without the `/bin/bash -l -c` part.

Then, my bash script is as follows, according to the [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/deployment/cron#environment):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RAILS_ENV=production

source /var/www/rvmuser/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p484

cd /path/to/my/rails_app

rake do:whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Is rake in the PATH of the cron user for running this shell?

Comment: You can try having the full path to rake in your task (ie, /usr/bin/rake). Also, you might have to specify the rails environment with RAILS_ENV=production.

Comment: It wasn't set, but after adding it I still get the same result.  Also tried electronaut's suggestion, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following format to run rake tasks, a little more explicit with the paths

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/rake -f /path/to/Rakefile daily_import RAILS_ENV=production
```

I also like to redirect output to a file so I can check the errors

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/rake -f /path/to/Rakefile daily_import RAILS_ENV=production > ~/daily_import.log 2>&1
```